# Laravel - All Image Paths Are Broke and Cannot Be Displayed

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I'm working with a project that is using Laravel (api) and Angular 5 (front-end) on GoDaddy. In order to use Laravel safely on GoDaddy, I had to put all the Laravel files one directory back from `public_html` and all the Angular files in `public_html`. In order for this to work properly, I had to move the Laravel public folder to `public_html` and point to the Laravel file's via an absolute path. Everything is working so I know I'm headed in the right direction.

*Laravel path* - `/home/website/laravel/`

*Public path* - `/home/website/public_html/`

The only problem I'm having is trying to serve-up images for an image gallery. I store all the images in Laravel's `storage` directory and save the image path's in the db. When it's time to load all the images via Angular, I call the api and it returns all the image name's in a collection and Angular appends the path. Here's an example - `https://website.com/storage/media/events/1/m_22721a76-8f0a-4ce2-97a5-e5ac169127a5.jpg`.

Since my images are kept one directory back from `public_html`, they cannot be reached and are broke. My first thought is to save all the images in a directory in `public_html`, but I'm not sure if I can change Laravel's `filesystems` config to allow that. I also thought about trying to use `.htaccess` to detect a certain path and redirect, but I couldn't get it to work. I feel like using Laravel's `filesystems` is the way to go, but couldn't get it to work, here is what I came up with:

## filesystems.php

```
'production' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('/home/website/public_html/storage/media/'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

## ImageGalleryController.php

```
if(App::environment('local'))
{
    Storage::disk('local')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/t_' . $path, (string) $thumb->encode());
}
else if(App::environment('test')) 
{
    Storage::disk('test')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/t_' . $path, (string) $thumb->encode());
}
else {
    Storage::disk('production')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/t_' . $path, (string) $thumb->encode());
}
```

With my current file setup, any ideas how I can display images from Laravel's storage directory?